# MySQL trigger on WAMP not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, wamp

I'm trying to autogenerate an ID when data is fed into the database. The trigger doesn't work and shows some problem on line 2. I tested the sql query and it works fine.

drop trigger if exists  db_name.trigger_name//

```
create trigger db_name.trigger_name after insert on db_name.table_name
begin
update db_name.table_name
SET scanID = concat(right(scanContent,2),
                    right(operatorID,2),
                    right(deviceID,2),
                    REPLACE (scanDate, '-', ''),
                    REPLACE (scanTime, ':', ''))

end 
//
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: What query did you run, because I can promise you

SET scanID = concat(right(scanContent,2),
                    right(operatorID,2),
                    right(deviceID,2),
                    REPLACE (scanDate, '-', ''),
                    REPLACE (scanTime, ':', ''))

is not valid MySQL syntax

Comment: Did you mean to do an update on the record?

Comment: Yes Nick, I want to update the DB. And you are right, I forgot to paste the update database line. The trigger gets formed. However, nothing happens when the record is created.

Comment: The trigger you wrote looks valid. But it will update every scan id in your table. What is the value of scanid for the new record after insert?

Comment: I insert an empty space through a PHP script. The data comes from an android device. The value of the scanID inserted by the sql query in the PHP script is ''(nothing).